# ffmpeg hangs on last frame during alphamerge

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to blur specific part of video using alphamerge command.
The command that I'm using is following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "odd resolution.3g2" -loop 1 -i cahceg0 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='320:178',split=3[er0][ero1][er2];[er0][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4:ap=0[alfb0];[er2]crop=256.0:18.956467:32.0:10.797836,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4[alfb1];[ero1][alfb0]overlay[v0];[v0][alfb1]overlay=32.0:10.797836[v1]" -map [v1] -c:a copy -c:v libx264 output.3g2
```

The whole process works normally until the very last one frame, then ffmpeg just hangs indefinitely with this last output

`frame=  312 fps= 19 q=27.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:17.22 bitrate= 243.5kbits/s speed=1.03x  .`

At this point only fps and speed value change. **The issue fixes if I remove '-loop 1' switch from second input or do not scale the first input** but then it does not blur the video I want it to be
I am attaching input files and ffmpeg log

[odd_resolution.3g2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bysYfSZAraaAVQTJ4nAu6IzDKt7y4hIv/view?usp=sharing) [cahceg0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBSICR-kkasl4sIPIkoZCjKzMyGRoUv-/view?usp=sharing) [ffmpeg_log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T6XKRJBrGy0-a7AWa8mo_1UMzWfSmceF/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the order of aliases in split command, so the aliases should be used in same order as they are declared in split expression else ffmpeg will stuck, following is fixed command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "odd resolution.3g2" -loop 1 -i cahceg0 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='320:178',split=3[er0][ero1][er2];[er0][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4:ap=0[alfb0];[er1]crop=256.0:18.956467:32.0:10.797836,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4[alfb1];[ero2][alfb0]overlay[v0];[v0][alfb1]overlay=32.0:10.797836[v1]" -map [v1] -c:a copy -c:v libx264 output.3g2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `repeatlast=0` switch to your filtercomplex

```
ffmpeg -y -i "odd resolution.3g2" -loop 1 -i cahceg0 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='320:178',split=3[er0][ero1][er2];[er0][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4:ap=0[alfb0];[er2]crop=256.0:18.956467:32.0:10.797836,boxblur=chroma_radius=4:luma_radius=4[alfb1];[ero1][alfb0]overlay[v0];[v0][alfb1]overlay=32.0:10.797836:repeatlast=0[v1]" -map [v1] -c:a copy -c:v libx264 output.3g2
```

Comment: Should repeatlast switch be added to last overlay statement in command?

Comment: Yes, because one of overlay filters will never stop because you use -loop 1, that basically says loop forever.

Comment: I tried a different variant of command(added a new coloured area along with blur area) and it makes the process stuck(even with repeatlast switch)

`ffmpeg -y -i "odd resolution.3g2" -loop 1 -i cahceg0 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='320:178',split=3[er0][ero1][er2];[er0][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=14:ap=0[alfb0];[er2]crop=92.492615:143.2:15.408203:17.9,boxblur=14[alfb1];color=0xBBBBBB:s=86x143[alfb2];[ero1][alfb0]overlay[v0];[v0][alfb1]overlay=15.408203:17.9[v1];[v1][alfb2]overlay=202.40965:17.9:repeatlast=0[v2]" -map [v2] -map 0:a? -c:a copy -c:v libx264 test.3g2`

Comment: You added color filter, yet another infinite length video source without option to limit its duration. Add shortest=1  to last overlay, right after repeatlast=0. Anyway this needs understanding of reading English written documentation. Follow FFmpeg filters documentation closely.